# Could multiple uses of the same keywords in image alt attributes hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, images, alt-attribute

Let's say on an e-commerce site that sells unique pens, on a particular pen's product page, the image of the pen has an `alt` attribute value of "unique red-striped pen"... and another product has "unique blue-spotted pen", etc... The keywords across all products being "unique" and "pen", which would also be helpful when it comes to SEO.

However, if the person just goes to the general "unique pens" category page and sees a list of thumbnail images, each with the words "unique" and "pen" in the `alt` attribute, would that potentially have a negative impact with regards to SEO by having the same keywords too many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the category page can be crawled (e.g., it's not dynamically generated), using the same keywords in all the `alt` attributes on that page might be considered to be [keyword stuffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_stuffing) by search engines like Google.

Google's [Penguin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin) update specifically targets things like this which might be construed as "blackhat" techniques. So even if done inadvertently, your site might be penalized. For more on this, see this [review](http://www.websitemagazine.com/content/blogs/posts/archive/2011/04/26/keyword-stuffing-alt-tags-for-google.aspx) on the subject at [Google's Webmaster Help](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/DrUljA0sEGk) forum.

Also, see the bottom of the section named "Create great alt text" here:  [Google Webmaster Tools:  Image publishing guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016)